# Find html tag and echo new code between

Tags: php, jquery, regex, search

I've been looking into this for some hours now and have read countless posts here on Stackoverflow and through Google. I've also read up on a few PHP methods and am studying up on some Regex but am not sure on the best method. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have some simple title tags in an hgroup like so:

```
<hgroup>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</hgroup>
```

Please note, the hgroup may have a `class` as well.

I need to search my page for the hgroup tag (with the possible class) and add some code on a new line becoming

```
<hgroup>
  <span>NEW LINE AND TEXT</span> 
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</hgroup>
```

I've found a few solutions to find a class or tag but am not sure how to add a new line of code successfully between.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1493698)

Comment: do u want it on jQuery?

Comment: @Antony I'd prefer it with regex.

Comment: Sure, I'd like to have a jQuery option. @Viscocent

Comment: Just to be sure this is clear, PHP create a long `string` which is equivalent to an `.html` page. Once the page PHP generated on the server is sent to the client (browser), PHP can't control anything else on this page. It's at this point where JavaScript enter the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$("hgroup") // note this could be the class name: you pass in a CSS selector
  .prepend( $("<span/>").text("New line and text") );
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/HzY6y/

Comment: @Mikel Ward just put your variable in the .text("<?php echo $variable?>")

Comment: Careful there, shouldn't mix javascript and PHP code. This make for unmaintainable code and a lot of headache. If you're doing something, do it correctly. Keep each in their bondaries, PHP generate the page, javascript take care of the interations once the page is served.